# Perl How to do optional regex match

Tags: regex, perl

Suppose following string

```
$doc=<<'TEXT_END';
<LI>11：20
           </LI>
<LI><a href="/showtime/ticket/4f3a3cc7017f4202b5add5803594fdd9/" class="openbox">13：55 &nbsp; <font color=a81234 size=-1>訂票</font>&nbsp;</a> </LI>

TEXT_END
```

How to capture 11：20 and 13：55 with one regular expression

I don't know how to do optional match
(letting the following two tag ignorable)

```
<a href=".....">
<font color="....">
```

訂票 means "book a ticket".(the website add a link when it is available for booking)

sorry for my bad english

below is my code, it doesn't work correctly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#use utf8;
use LWP::Simple;

binmode(STDIN, ':encoding(utf8)');
binmode(STDOUT, ':encoding(utf8)');
binmode(STDERR, ':encoding(utf8)'); 

my $doc = get 'http://www.atmovies.com.tw/showtime/theater_t06609_a06.html';

my @movies = ($doc =~ /<a href="\/movie\/([a-z]+\d+)\/">([^><]+)<\/a>.+?<UL>(.+?)<\/UL>/gs);

for($i=1; $i<=$#movies; $i+=3){
    print "$movies[$i]\n";
    print $movies[$i+1]."\n\n";

    #this work just fine!
    my @times = ($movies[$i+1] =~ /<LI>([^<>]+)\r\n\s+<\/LI>/g);
    for($j=0; $j<=$#times; $j++){
        print "$times[$j]\n";
    }

    #this regex doesn't work correctly, it catch nothing
    @times_available=($movies[$i+1] =~ /<LI><a href="\/showtime\/ticket\/[0-9a-f]{32}\/" class="openbox">([^><\s]+) &nbsp; <font color=a81234 size=-1>☆訂票<\/font>&nbsp;<\/a> <\/LI>/g);
    for($j=0; $j<=$#times_available; $j++){
        print "$times_available[$j]\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: http://www.atmovies.com.tw/showtime/theater_t06609_a06.html

Comment: 11：20 in this string ":" is not colon. Please try to escape it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this

```
@times = $doc =~ m/>\s*([\d：]+)/g;
```

Here is the full test program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use utf8;

use Data::Dumper;

my $doc=<<'TEXT_END';
<LI>11：20
           </LI>
       <LI><a href="/showtime/ticket/4f3a3cc7017f4202b5add5803594fdd9/" class="openbox">13：55 &nbsp; <font color=a81234 size=-1>訂票</font>&nbsp;</a> </LI>

TEXT_END

my @times = $doc =~ m/>\s*([\d：]+)/g;

print Dumper(\@times);
```

And the result:

```
$ perl t020.pl 
$VAR1 = [
          '11：20',
          '13：55'
        ];
```

Comment: @TimHsu Please copy and paste my code and try again. Notice that you are using a chinese `：`, not English `:`, in your `$doc`.

Comment: thanks a lot. I noticed my regular expression is too long and too complex. the test program run just fine with $doc copied from the Internet! However, the regex you gave can not parse the source code retrieved from the web.

Comment: @TimHsu I have tested your code, if I remove all these `binmode()`, the output looks normally to me (I can read Chinese). My local setting: terminal character encoding is UTF-8, LANG is zh_CN.UTF-8

Comment: I tested it on koding VM which local LANG might not be zh_cn or zh_tw and terminal encoding is UTF-8(some chinese characters might  still be entire invisible(ex: chinese colon)). I think this is not the problem because even on my Windows PC with strawberry perl, the parsing result does not change. I then replaced all the ： to :, it worked just fine.

Comment: On my personal computer, I enables binmode() and using utf8, the output looks normally.It seems the code is not portable. how to fix this?replace all chinese colon to normal colon?

Comment: binmode(STDOUT, ':encoding(big5)'); #it work just fine in CMD

Comment: @TimHsu Because your code has non-ASCII character, you should `use utf8;` to inform `perl` that the encoding of your program is UTF-8. Additionally, your calls to `binmode()` should be `binmode(..., ':encoding(UTF-8)');`.

Comment: @TimHsu I guess the actually output also depends on the encoding of your terminal. Your code (with `use utf8;`) also works in terminal with `LANG=en_US.utf8`, character encoding Unicode UTF-8.

Comment: you are right, the key is "using utf8". it will affect the process of interpretation. binmode(STDOUT, XXX) only convert output encoding to the specified encoding and it does not affect interpreting process.